# Brushless DC Motor -> Generator Power

Tags: power, motor, brushless-dc-motor, generator

I would like to know the approximate Voltage I could produce if I used this motor as a generator... If anyone could help me out with this I would greatly appreciate it!

[image: DC Motor]

Comment: You have a single phase ac motor.  Why do you believe it is a brushless DC motor?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat to be fair, a brushless "DC" motor is just a three-phase permanent magnet AC motor wearing a trench coat.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the name plate, that is almost certainly not going to operate as a generator. However, if I'm wrong, put the shaft into the chuck of a drill and give it a whirl while the leads are hooked up to a multimeter. Typically you would have at least 3-leads on a brushless DC motor (not including earth).

Comment: What would you guys say would be the best motor to use as a high output generator? Least amount of revolutions for most volts?

Comment: RyanW:  High voltage, low RPM??...that'd be Wimshurst machine or Van de Graaff generator...likely not what you want, since these are low-power.

Comment: @RyanW why do you keep insisting on using a motor as a generator? Why not use a generator as a generator considering that is what a generator is designed to do? What is the load you are trying to power? You specify a generator based on the load. The open-circuit voltage is proportional to the shaft speed. You also have to consider input torque requirements? What are you using to spin the shaft?

Comment: @MOSFET - thank you for your input… I am using myself on a bicycle, a chain & sprocket to the shaft.